# Unmount hard drive debian

Tags: debian, hard-drive

hey, i accidentally mounted the same hard drive twice to two different directories, how can I remove one of the mounts?

I have this

```
/dev/sdb1             459G  199M  435G   1% /disk2
/dev/sdb1             459G  199M  435G   1% /var/www/disk2
```

and i want to remove

```
    /dev/sdb1             459G  199M  435G   1% /disk2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*umount /path/where/its/mounted*... in your example

`umount /disk2`

or

`umount /var/www/disk2`

depending on which one you want to umount.